# Brightway2 and carculator: LCIA not characterizing CO2 biosphere flows?

Tags: brightway

I have recently started working with the [carculator](https://github.com/romainsacchi/carculator/) package with bw2. I have exported LCI from carculator to import into bw2 to conduct independent analyses. However, when calculating LCA scores with the imported data, bw2 seems not to be accounting biosphere flows for CO2 (fossil and non-fossil).

For example, the carculator LCA (e.g. IPCC 2013, GWP100) for vehicle X gives 0.37 kg CO2 per km. However, when LCI data is imported into bw2, the bw2 LCA gives a value of 0.14 kg CO2 per km which corresponds only to the technosphere activities (production of vehicles etc.). The missing 0.23 kg CO2 per km (0.23 kg of Carbon dioxide, fossil in the LCI biosphere) does not seem to be characterized in the LCA score. I think this might an easy fix somewhere but not sure why this is happening?

Below is the initial code that is taken directly from the example notebooks which export and import carculator LCI into Brightway2.

```
bw.databases
del bw.databases['carculator_lci_car']

cip = CarInputParameters()
cip.static()

scope = {
    'powertrain':['ICEV-d', 'PHEV-p'],
}

dcts, array = fill_xarray_from_input_parameters(cip, scope=scope)

cm = CarModel(array, cycle='WLTC')
cm.set_all()

ic = InventoryCar(cm)

ic.export_lci(
    software="brightway2",
    directory=r"/Users/js3700/Untitled Folder 1",
    ecoinvent_version='3.8',
    format="file"
)

i = ic.export_lci(ecoinvent_version='3.8', format="bw2io")

if "carculator export" in bw.databases:
    del bw.databases['carculator export']
    i.apply_strategies()

i.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location', 'reference product'))
i.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'categories'))
i.match_database('ecoinvent 3.8', fields=('name', 'unit', 'location', 'reference product'))
i.match_database("biosphere3", fields=('name', 'unit', 'categories'))

i.statistics()

if not list(i.unlinked):
    i.write_database()
else:
    i.add_unlinked_flows_to_biosphere_database()
    i.write_database()
```

```
****************** IMPORTANT BACKGROUND PARAMETERS ******************
 * The country of use is CH.
 * Power and energy batteries produced in CN using ['NMC-622'] chemistry/ies
 * Battery cell, NMC-622
between 2000 and 2015, % of renewable: 60.0.
     * between 2010 and 2025, % of renewable: 68.0.
     * between 2020 and 2035, % of renewable: 77.0.
     * between 2030 and 2045, % of renewable: 85.0.
     * between 2040 and 2055, % of renewable: 88.0.
     * between 2050 and 2065, % of renewable: 88.0.
 * diesel is completed by biodiesel - cooking oil.
     * in 2000 _________________________________________ 0.0%
     * in 2010 _________________________________________ 0.0%
     * in 2020 _________________________________________ 5.0%
     * in 2030 _________________________________________ 5.0%
     * in 2040 _________________________________________ 5.0%
     * in 2050 _________________________________________ 5.0%
 * petrol is completed by bioethanol - wheat straw.
     * in 2000 _________________________________________ 0.0%
     * in 2010 _________________________________________ 0.0%
     * in 2020 _________________________________________ 1.0%
     * in 2030 _________________________________________ 1.0%
     * in 2040 _________________________________________ 1.0%
     * in 2050 _________________________________________ 1.0%
 * *********************************************************************
0% [##############################] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00 | Item ID: 1549
Total time elapsed: 00:00:01
0% [##############################] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00 | Item ID: 1549
Total time elapsed: 00:00:02
Applying strategy: link_iterable_by_fields
Applying strategy: link_iterable_by_fields
Applying strategy: link_iterable_by_fields
Applying strategy: link_iterable_by_fields
499 datasets
14616 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Writing activities to SQLite3 database:
0% [##############################] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
Total time elapsed: 00:00:02
Title: Writing activities to SQLite3 database:
  Started: 03/09/2023 12:17:03
  Finished: 03/09/2023 12:17:06
  Total time elapsed: 00:00:02
  CPU %: 84.10
  Memory %: 3.76
Created database: carculator_lci_car
```

Below, following the example notebook, I run the following LCAs in Brightway2 with the results ranging from 0.099-0.129 kg CO2 eq per km.

```
FU = [{act:1} for act in bw.Database('carculator_lci_car') if 'transport, car' in act['name'] and "Lower medium" in act['name']]

bw.calculation_setups['multiLCA'] = {'inv': FU, 'ia': [('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')]}
myMultiLCA = bw.MultiLCA('multiLCA')
df_impact = pd.DataFrame(columns = [('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')],
                         data = myMultiLCA.results,
                         index=[(k['name'], k['location'], k["database"]) for i in FU for k in i])

df_impact.head(10)
```

```
    (IPCC 2013, climate change, GWP 100a)
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2050, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.099484
(transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2020, Euro-6.2, CH, carculator_lci_car)  0.128942
(transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2030, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.122192
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2040, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.099733
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2030, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.103343
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2020, Euro-6.2, CH, carculator_lci_car)  0.105889
(transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2040, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.120893
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2010, Euro-4, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.110797
(transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2000, Euro-2, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.115398
(transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2050, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car)    0.123462
```

However, the expected values that obtained from calculator and the example notebooks range 0.145-0.274 kg CO2 eq per km...

```
(IPCC 2013, climate change, GWP 100a)
transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2020, Euro-6.2, CH, carculator_lci_car    0.249001
transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2010, Euro-4, CH, carculator_lci_car  0.274288
transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2050, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car  0.145473
transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2030, Euro-7, CH, carculator_lci_car  0.226964
transport, car, plugin gasoline hybrid, Lower medium, 2020, Euro-6.2, CH, carculator_lci_car    0.222947
```

I have traced it back that in the LCIA the Carbon dioxide biosphere flows coming from the tailpipe emissions of vehicles are not being included in the impact assessment although they seem to be linked/matched in the LCI excel sheets.

Using "transport, car, diesel, Lower medium, 2010, Euro-4, CH" as an example the expected value is 0.274288 but I get 0.110797. The difference is 0.163491 which is nearly equivalent to Carbon dioxide (0.15788 kg per km) biosphere flows + other biosphere minor contributors, highlighted in the actual excel LCI below...

[image]